# Java 8 expiration after a duration

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Can't figure out how to do in java 8 (without calendar) for this simple method:

```
 import java.time.Duration;
 import java.util.Date;
  [...]
/**
 * true if date + duration is before now()
 * @param date 
 * @param d
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isDateExpired (Date date, Duration d) {
 // how to do ?
}
```

Comment: As @Misha said Date has been replaced by Period. Read about Duration / Period here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider getting rid of `java.util.Date`.  Even when you must deal with it due to legacy code, escape into `java.time` equivalent and operate there:

```
return date.toInstant().plus(d).isBefore(Instant.now());
```